# How to split a sequence into two pieces by predicate?

Tags: scala

How do I split a sequence into two lists by a predicate?

Alternative: I can use `filter` and `filterNot`, or write my own method, but isn't there a better more general (built-in) method ?

Answer (score 219, accepted):

By using `partition` method:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4).partition(x => x % 2 == 0)
res0: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(2, 4),List(1, 3))
```

Comment: `val (even, odd) = List(1,2,3,4).partition(x => x % 2 == 0)` is a way to destruct the resulting tuple of `partition` in a readable way.

Comment: One can shorten the function inside partition to `_ % 2 == 0`.

Answer (score 150):

Good that `partition` was the thing you wanted -- there's another method that also uses a predicate to split a list in two: `span`.

The first one, [partition](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@partition(p:A=>Boolean):(Repr,Repr)) will put all "true" elements in one list, and the others in the second list.

[span](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@span(p:A=>Boolean):(Repr,Repr)) will put all elements in one list until an element is "false" (in terms of the predicate). From that point forward, it will put the elements in the second list.

```
scala> Seq(1,2,3,4).span(x => x % 2 == 0)
res0: (Seq[Int], Seq[Int]) = (List(),List(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. When the list is ordered by a related criterion, this makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Might be helpful to mention that where `partition` is equivalent to `(filter, filterNot)`, `span` is equivalent to `(takeWhile, dropWhile)`.

Answer (score 18):

You might want to take a look at [the Scala API docs](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/) - it allows you to search the scala standard library for functions by their signature. For example, type the following:

```
List[A] => (A => Boolean) => (List[A], List[A])
```

You would see **partition**.

Comment: scalex.org domain is currently dead. But there is alternative - http://scala-search.org/ ;-).

Comment: Teaching how to catch a fish!

Comment: @monnef Any alternative for your alternative for 2020 ? :)

Comment: There is no alternatives :(. 2020 ... is the worst

Comment: The Scala API docs now allow for searching with type sugnatures

Answer (score 14):

You can also use foldLeft if you need something a little extra.  I just wrote some code like this when partition didn't cut it:

```scala
val list:List[Person] = /* get your list */
val (students,teachers) = 
  list.foldLeft(List.empty[Student],List.empty[Teacher]) {
    case ((acc1, acc2), p) => p match {
      case s:Student => (s :: acc1, acc2)
      case t:Teacher  => (acc1, t :: acc2)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Very nice way to use a tuple and foldLeft. I ended up using a ListBuffer to efficiently keep the two lists in the same order but otherwise it was spot on for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I know I might be late for the party and there are more specific answers, but you could make good use of `groupBy`

```
val ret = List(1,2,3,4).groupBy(x => x % 2 == 0)

ret: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Boolean,List[Int]] = Map(false -> List(1, 3), true -> List(2, 4))

ret(true)
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 4)

ret(false)
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 3)
```

This makes your code a bit more future-proof if you need to change the condition into something non boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a list into more than 2 pieces, and ignore the bounds, you could use something like this (modify if you need to search for ints)

```
def split(list_in: List[String], search: String): List[List[String]] = {
  def split_helper(accum: List[List[String]], list_in2: List[String], search: String): List[List[String]] = {
    val (h1, h2) = list_in2.span({x: String => x!= search})
    val new_accum = accum :+ h1
    if (h2.contains(search)) {
      return split_helper(new_accum, h2.drop(1), search) 
    }
    else {
    return accum
    }
  }
  return split_helper(List(), list_in, search)
}

// TEST

// split(List("a", "b", "c", "d", "c", "a"), {x: String => x != "x"})
```